# Data Binding on a custom DependenctProperty of a Cutom Shape doesn't work

Tags: .net, xaml, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am relatively new in **.NET**, so, most probably I am doing something dumb, But all I have done is that 
I have created a Custom Shape with XAML which is basically a circle.

**Circle.xaml:**

```
<local:Closed2DArea
x:Class="GeoDraw.CustomShapes.Circle"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:GeoDraw.CustomShapes"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Name="circle">
<Path.Data>
    <EllipseGeometry Center="{Binding Center, ElementName=circle}" RadiusX="{Binding Radius, ElementName=circle}" RadiusY="{Binding Radius, ElementName=circle}"/>
</Path.Data>
</local:Closed2DArea>
```

Now, the **Circle.xaml.cs:** file has two `DependencyProperty` : `CenterProperty` and `RadiusProperty`

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Center", typeof(Point), typeof(Circle), null);
    public Point Center
    {
        get => (Point)GetValue(CenterProperty);
        set => SetProperty(CenterProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(double), typeof(Circle), null);
    public double Radius
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(RadiusProperty);
        set => SetProperty(RadiusProperty, value);
    }
```

The `SetProperty` method here is declared in the base class `Closed2DArea` which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` like this:

```
public abstract class Closed2DArea : Path , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void SetProperty<T>( DependencyProperty prop, T value, [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        SetValue(prop, value);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
/*constructors and other methods*/
}
```

All this works fine when I use this shape  in a view with normal property setting, like `<CustomShape:Circle Center="20 20" Radius="10">`.

**Problem:**:

The problem occurs when I try to use data binding like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="maingrid" >
    <TextBox x:Name="tbox" Text="80" Margin="258,61,82,189" Width="100" Height="30"/>
    <CustomShape:Circle Center="100,80" Radius="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbox}"/>
</Grid>
```

The Binding here doesn't work, the circle never changes it's radius. I am stuck with this for like 5 hours, tried a lot, but don't know what am I missing. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to be mixing INotifyPropertyChanged with Dependency Properties.  They're different things.

You should use the `propdp` shortcut in VS and not change the `SetValue` function it uses.

Dependency Properties automatically will work with data binding, that's what the extra setup is doing.

INotifyPropertyChanged is to get binding and such to work with regular properties.

I think part of your problem here is you're trying to create a control but using another non-`DependencyObject` as a base.  To use Dependency Properties you need to inherit from DependencyObject.  Usually you get this when you create something off a `UserControl` or a `Control`.

Otherwise you should only be using regular properties with INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: `UseControl` did the work !! But can you explain why `Path` could not do that? Both of them have `DependencyObject` in their inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency properties probably need callback methods that are invoked when their internal value is set, e.g.:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Center", typeof(Point), typeof(Circle), new PropertyMetadata(default(Point), CenterPropertyChanged));

private static void CenterPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var circle = dependencyObject as Circle;
    var center = (Point)args.NewValue;

    // do something with these values
}
```

Move all custom logic from the setter method into this callback method - Data Binding doesn't invoke your setter method, instead the dependency property's value is set directly (I guess this is what you're experiencing).

Comment: The `RadiusProperty` is bound to the `RadiusXProperty` and `RadiusYProperty` of the `EllipseGeometry`. So, changing the internal value should change the radius of the circle, but it doesn't. And also, I tried your solution, didn't work. The circle just don't change it's radius.